# i want take value from url with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want take id value from the link cause it does not change:

```php
<?php $se = mysql_query("select * from tee") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($se)){
echo'<a class="link" href="?id=" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="m'.$row->id.'">
    '.$row->id.'
</a>';  }                
?>

 <?php 

 $se1 = mysql_query("select * from tee") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($se1)) {
  echo '<div id="m'.$row1->id.'" class="reveal-modal">
    <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness</h1>
    <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
';}?>
```

the first div is appear number and the second div the light box content

I want take id value from the link cause it does not change

Comment: please edit my code cause i don,t understand ajax

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want, but I think you want one of/the URL get parameters, this will get you started: http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

Answer (score 0):

If you want get html data attribute value, you can use the following:

```
$("a.big-link").data("reveal-id")
```